# Adding different sections in Crystal Reports for details

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2010, sections

I know how to add sections, groups etc but I am just trying to show something like this:

```
************************************Section1**************************************
Name:--------    LastName:---------------    Address:---------------------------
Phone:-------    Mobile:-----------------    Email:-----------------------------

************************************Section 2*************************************
Amount:--------------------------   Salary:----------------------- Slips:--------------
CarLoan:---------------- Associated Bank:----------------------------------------------

********************************Section 3*******************************************
CompanyName:------------------------ Address:--------------------------- Phone:--------
Correpondence:----------------------------------------  MailBox No:--------------------
```

How to achieve this and sections are around 10 and I want to show them on the same page, If user clicks on one section then it can open in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found a way, I added sub reports and that was quite handy to do for each section.